# Multiplos loops no mesmo Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um form com 3 botoes para importar 3 arquivos diferentes ao mesmo tempo. Acontece que quando eu aciono um segundo botão o anterior interrompe o processamento.

```
    private void btnImp1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            totalImpo1 = 0;
            using var file = new StreamReader(txtArq1.Text);
            string? line;
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                totalImpo1++;
                progressBar1.Value = totalImpo1;
                label7.Text = totalImpo1.ToString();
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            file.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void btnImp2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            totalImpo2 = 0;
            using var file = new StreamReader(txtArq2.Text);
            string? line;
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                totalImpo2++;
                progressBar2.Value = totalImpo2;
                label8.Text = totalImpo2.ToString();
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            file.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJb09.png)

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma sugestão para o seu caso. Espero que o ajude.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        new TaskFactory().StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                CarregarArquivo(txtArq1.Text, progressBar1);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }


        });
                
    }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new TaskFactory().StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                CarregarArquivo(txtArq2.Text, progressBar2);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }


        });

        
    }
delegate void CarregarArquivoCallback(string path, ProgressBar progressBar);
    private void CarregarArquivo(string path, ProgressBar progressBar)
    {

        if (progressBar.InvokeRequired)
        {
            CarregarArquivoCallback d = new CarregarArquivoCallback(CarregarArquivo);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { path, progressBar });
        }
        else
        {
            using (var file = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                int totalImpo1 = 0;
                string line;
                progressBar.Maximum = 0;
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    progressBar.Maximum += 1;
                    totalImpo1++;
                    progressBar.Value = totalImpo1;
                }
                file.Close();
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).